# Sending and receiving JSON

Tags: netty

I am using Apache HttpComponets to post data like this to Netty. I use Gson for working JSON.

```
Request.Post("http://localhost:9090/print").bodyString(getJSon(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON),
```

This netty code does not seem to receive the JSON response. I am sure that my code is wrong. What could be the error here ?

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
                                                    throws Exception {
    logger.info( "channelRead" + msg );
    if( msg instanceof HttpRequest ){
        this.request = ( HttpRequest ) msg;
        logger.info( "[" + request.getUri()  + "]");
    }
    if( msg instanceof HttpContent ){
        HttpContent content = (HttpContent)msg;
        ByteBuf buf = content.content();
        logger.info( "[" + buf.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8)   + "]");
           if (msg instanceof LastHttpContent) {
                LastHttpContent trailer = (LastHttpContent) msg;
                writeResponse( trailer, ctx);
           }
    }
}



private boolean writeResponse(HttpObject currentObj, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    logger.info( getJSon() );
    ByteBuf response = Unpooled.copiedBuffer( getJSon(),
                                              CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

    ctx.write( response );
    /* Where is 'isKeepAlive' method in the API ? */
    //boolean keepAlive = isKeepAlive(request);
    //keepAlive;
    return false;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call ctx.writeAndFlush(...) to actual flush it out to the socket.

Comment: Actually I couldn't receive the JSON and print it. What is the type of 'Object' ? Seems that both 'instanceof' checks fail.

Comment: `((ByteBuf) msg ).toString(io.netty.util.CharsetUtil.US_ASCII)`        

    INFO nioEventLoopGroup-3-1 com.remote.printer.PrintResponseHandler - POST /print HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host: localhost:9090
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3 (java 1.5)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate